# Experience editor: Navigate to item and Select media views empty?

Tags: experience-editor, media-library

I have a lot of pages and media items in my database, but the **Navigate to item** and the **Select media** panes are completely empty and search does not return any results.

My initial thought was that something with the search index was broken. So I rebuilt them, but without luck.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshots]

I do get this, when using Chrome Developer Tools

[image]

Comment: did you try to rebuild master index ?

Comment: Yes, at least I think so. I rebuilt all indexes in the indexing manager. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/HPKD8

Comment: and no errors? did you try again after you rebuild the index?

Comment: No errors, and the master index reports as "Healthy". See previous screenshot. However, I don't understand what "Number of fields: -1" means.

Comment: One thing that might be of interest is that the console logs this: http://imgur.com/a/8Qhl0

Comment: @chilly I think it best to take this to a chat room or to Slack for diagnosing the problem. Then we can update this question with an answer... if we find one :)

Comment: Good idea. Will do that tomorrow. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 1):

The empty Select media pane was solved by adding a missing config file

> Heading into the App_Config\Include folder, I sure enough found a sneaky “Sitecore.Speak.ContentSearch.Solr.config.example” hiding away.  Why was it not named “Sitecore.ContentSearchSpeak.Speak.Solr.config.example” so it showed up with all the other configs? I have no idea.  Either way, when you open this file, you see exactly what you’re looking for: Renaming that file to remove the “.example” extension leaves me with something I like.

Read more: http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2016/05/16/sitecore-8-1-the-select-media-speak-ui-and-solr/